# Generic function for preview images before upload

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-4

I have a form with a feature with uploading images on different columns. I want to preview those images before upload. I have a function which does this task on single upload which is as follows:

```
 function readURL(input) {

     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {                 
             $('#profileimagesrc').attr('src', e.target.result);
         }

         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
 }
$("#profileimage").change(function() {
     readURL(this);

 });
```

But as I have multiple columns as:

```
<div class="form-row">
 <div><span class="form-title">Profile Image</span></div>
  <li class="form-control" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
   <img id="profileimagesrc" src="image/Image-default.jpg" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; margin-left: 11px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
    <input type="file" name="profileimage" id="profileimage" onchange="readURL(this);">

     </li>
      </div>

<div class="form-row">
 <div><span class="form-title">Book Image</span></div>
  <li class="form-control" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
   <img id="bookimagesrc" src="image/Image-default.jpg" style="width: 160px; height: 160px; margin-left: 11px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
    <input type="file" name="bookimage" id="bookimage" onchange="readURL(this);">

     </li>
      </div>
```

I want to create a generic function so that I could use the function once to preview the image.

These is what I did:

```
 function readURL(input) {

     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {
             var imagesrc = input.parent().find('img',id());
             $('#imagesrc').attr('src', e.target.result);
         }

         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
 }

 $(".image").change(function() {
     var image = this.id;
     readURL(image);

 });


 </script>
```

This function works well:
    $(".image").change(function() {...}

I think I am unable to select the id of image for the parent . Please guide me how to select the id of the  tag by selecting the id of the image.

Answer (score 0):

May this be the HTML:

```
 <div class="form-row">
 <div><span class="form-title">Profile Image</span></div>
  <li class="form-control" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
 <img src="image/Image-default.jpg" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;    margin-left: 11px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
  <input type="file" name="profileimage" onchange="readURL(this);">
</li>
<li class="form-control" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
 <img src="image/Image-default.jpg" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;    margin-left: 11px; margin-bottom: 5px;" />
  <input type="file" name="bookimage" onchange="readURL(this);">
</li>
 </div>
```

Then here goes the generic function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function readURL(input) {

     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {
             $(input).siblings().attr('src', e.target.result);
         }

         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
 }


 </script>
```